# How do people develop emulators?

Tags: javascript, concepts

I hope this is right area on Stack Exchange to ask this question.  People out there have built emulators for every game console but I don't understand how they do it. I consider myself (and have the professional title of) a senior level developer in several languages including Javascript but I don't have the faintest idea about how to begin writing an emulator in Javascript. How do they figure out how to read the ROMs and emulate the game?

Comment: For starters, you probably want to use a lower-level language than JavaScript.  Emulating a console involves emulating various CPUs, which requires a lot of bit-twiddling, and the implicit conversions that JS is notorious for will destroy you.

Comment: This is covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written

Comment: An emulator is in part a domain specific language for a particular machine code.  Look at (for example) the 6502 instruction set and consider what it would take to write an interpreter for that.  Things become more complex with IO, but there is a start.

Comment: Not to offend, but I frankly wouldn't expect a senior, grandmaster, or any level of a PHP/JS developer to be particularly aware of things like that. It's a long ways off from your domain, I have equally seen people who've spent their careers becoming black-belt-ninja-rockstar-uber-guru-llama embedded C devs who had zero understanding of front-end web development. They're immensely different domains with nigh no overlap, so don't expect because you've a great skill in one domain, that somehow means you should defaultly have great skill in another. We all have to start over when we transition

Comment: Having attempted to build a Javascript emulator as a semester project which I did not succeed at, I can tell you it is incredibly difficult. You can do all kinds of crazy optimizations to make the experience more [real](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2011/08/accuracy-takes-power-one-mans-3ghz-quest-to-build-a-perfect-snes-emulator/) and these take even more skill than just the basic nuts and bolts. The attempt I made was with knowledge of CPUs and how they work, having taken a class in computer architecture. Didn't help as much as I'd have liked.

Comment: Technically, you are building a simulator. An emulator is hardware component used to act as a specific processor and is normally implemented using FPGA or so. A simulator is a software used to act as a specific processor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you've never had the pleasure of a college course where you had to self-assemble and disassemble your own code, or design a CPU.  It's tedious, but actually not that difficult.

Take the Microchip PIC [instruction set](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31029a.pdf) as an example, which I chose because it is very simple, only 35 instructions.  If you look at the "14-bit instruction word" column in the table on page 3, those are the bits that actually get written to flash, what is mostly used today instead of ROM.  Each instruction has a unique fixed prefix.  `ADDWF` has a prefix of `00 0111`, for example.

An emulator just has to check the value from the ROM against all the instruction prefixes until it finds a match, then parse the rest of the instruction.  For `ADDWF`, the `d` bit becomes the `d` argument, and the `f` bits become the `f` argument.  Then you just use those arguments to do an add in Javascript, something like:

```
addwf = function(f, d) {
  if (d == 0)
     w = w + registers[f]
  else
     registers[f] = w + registers[f]
}
```

Of course, there are also carry bits and such to set, but that's the basic idea to emulating a CPU.  For a game console, you also have to emulate the IO, but there are technical specification documents around the internet to help you know how to do that.  For example, writing an `0x0000ff` to a certain memory location might turn a specific pixel blue.  Your emulator then just has to detect writes to that emulated memory location from your emulated CPU and translate it into whatever Javascript commands turn a pixel blue.

That's a gross oversimplification.  It takes a considerable amount of optimization work to make an emulation fast enough to handle the desired frame rate of a game, but those are the basic principles.

Comment: Not only does an emulator have to be "fast enough", it also can't be *too* fast. Modern PC CPUs can execute instructions orders of magnitude faster than an Atari 2600 or NES. Even with the layer of abstraction required in translating ROM instructions for these consoles into meaningful PC operations, an emulator executing an NES ROM as fast as the underlying PC hardware can do so would be unplayable. This requires a more difficult layer of execution timing, which must send instructions to the PC only as fast as the actual console would have run them.

Comment: Related: [Accuracy at the expense of CPU](http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2011/08/accuracy-takes-power-one-mans-3ghz-quest-to-build-a-perfect-snes-emulator/).  In short, the more accurate the emulation, the more CPU it requires, but the less you need to hack around certain edge cases.